# Add y-min and y-max on chart column

Tags: vb.net, charts, diagram

I'm trying to figure out how to make a diagram to show column with a starting y and a ending y value.

For example, i would like to have a diagram like this:

```
|
|   X
|   X
|___X________
|   X 
|
```

That is, y-lowest = -1, y-higest = 3

If i do it like this:

```
Dim s As Series
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
s.Name = "My column"
s.Points.AddY(-1)
s.Points.AddY(4)
myDiagram.Series.Add(s)
```

i get a result like this:

```
|    X
|    X
|    X
|____X_______
|   X 
|
```

In the real case i have 3 series (named A,B,C in example), both with max and min and the result with the solution above is:

```
|
|         A
|         A B C
|_________A_B_C__
|   A B C 
|     B C
```

The result i would like is this:

```
|
|   A      
|   A B C  
|___A_B_C______
|   A B C 
|     B C
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured it out.

i had to do it like this:

```
AddXY(x, MyHighNumber)
AddXY(x, MyLowNumber)
```

and for the first column x = 1, the second column x = 2 etc.